# Are there infinite numbers $\not\equiv 2 \pmod {n}$, where n is any prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

It's been proven there are infinitely many primes. This means that there exist infinitely many $m$ such that for all other prime $n$, "$m \not\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$".

My question is then, would this imply there exist infinitely many $m$ such that for all prime $n$ other than $n=m-2$, "$m \not\equiv 2 \pmod{n}$"? How about $4 \pmod{n}$?

Finally how about equivalent to **neither** 2 **nor** 4$\pmod{n}$?

---

**Edit:** To clarify my final question, another way of saying this would be "Are there infinitely many numbers, $m$, such that $m-2$ and $m-4$ are prime?" This closely approximates the twin prime conjecture, but just states it differently.

---

**Edit:** Still trying to clear ambiguity. Pick a number $m$. Is $m\equiv 2 \pmod{n}$ for some prime $n$ other than when $n=m-2$? Then that $m$ doesn't work. For instance, $m=11$: $11\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ so 11 doesn't work. But consider $m=13$. There are no prime $n$'s  we could insert such that $13\equiv 2 \pmod{n}$ other than when $n=m-2$ -- $11=13-2$. Thus $m=13$ works. Are there infinitely many working $m$'s? My final question (see above): "are there infinitely many that work for both 2 and 4 simultaneously?"

Comment: $mn+1\not\equiv 2\pmod {n}$ for any $m$ if $n>1$. You don't need anything about primes to prove that.

Comment: What does "congruent to $2 \pmod n$" mean to you?

Comment: @pjs36 For instance, 5 is congruent to $2 \pmod{3}$, thus 5 doesn't work.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis In the same sense as infinite primes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I want something not $\equiv 2 \pmod{n}$ for **all** prime n, not just one in particular.

Comment: @pjs36 Hastily replied and have to correct myself. 5 would work. Obviously $n+2 \equiv 2 \pmod{n}$ for all $n$. Should have added "infinite numbers not $\equiv 2 \pmod{n}$ for all prime $n$ except for  the number itself $-2$."

Comment: @user3363795 An aside about usage: Everywhere you've written "infinite", it should be "infinitely many". For example, there are no "infinite primes", but there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: The OP answered their own question.

Comment: This is the problem with putting "for every" at the end of a sentence. $\exists m\text{ ... } \forall n$ is ambiguous. It is unclear which has precedence - does the sentence mean $\forall n\exists m$ or $\exists m\forall n$? @user3363795

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right, Thomas. Really struggled on how to put it. I'm far enough removed from math courses as well to fully grasp which of your two at the bottom fits. Would you suggest an edit to the original post that would clear it up? I've added some, but it may still be ambiguous.

Comment: "Does there exist infinitely many $m$ such that for all prime $n$, $m\equiv 2\pmod n$." @user3363795

Comment: @user3363795 The first edit is very confusing: there is a very big difference between $m \equiv 2 \pmod n$ and $m=n-2$.  Please clarify which one you mean, because it certainly is not "another way of saying" the same question.

Comment: @ErickWong When $n=m-2$ obviously $m \equiv 2 \pmod n$. I want other than when $n=m-2$.

Comment: If $m-2$ is prime, $n=m-2$ will be the **only** case where $m \equiv 2\pmod n$.

Comment: @user3363795 I agree.  So are you asking whether $m \equiv 2 \pmod n$ for some prime $n$ (as it says in your title) or $m-2$ is prime (as it says in your edit)??

Comment: Aren't they the same? Asking "Does there exist infinitely many $m$ such that for all prime $n$ other than $n=m-2$, $m \not\equiv 2 \pmod n$?" is the same as asking, "Are there infinitely many $m$ such that $m-2$ is prime?" since you agree that if $m-2$ is prime, $n=m-2$ is the only case where $m \equiv 2 \pmod n$, isn't it?

Comment: @user3363795 Ok, I agree that the question body is an internally consistent, if a bit convoluted, way to phrase the question.  Do you see how the title is utterly misleading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36274/discussion-between-user3363795-and-erick-wong).

Comment: Sorry. I'm a 4th grade math teacher doing my best to participate on this site. I'd happily make things easier to understand, but I'm not sure what better to put. Someone else suggested, "Do there exist infinitely many $m$ such that for all prime $n$ other than $n=m-2$, $m \equiv 2 \pmod{n}$," but I'm afraid editing again will make someone else confused or angry. Also, I'd like to change it to better address my final question specifically, but don't think I stand a chance of that one. Your suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

If $x\geq 4$ and $n$ is a prime divisor of $x-2$ then $x\not = n$ and $x\equiv 2 \pmod n.$

Comment: I get this now. You use $x$ where I use $m$. This says basically if $x-2$ isn't prime, there must be some $n$ such that $x \equiv 2 \pmod{n}$. My edit at the bottom of my original question now addresses this.

Comment: @user3363795 Even if $x-2$ is prime then there will be a prime $n$ such that $x \equiv 2 \pmod n$, namely $n=x-2$.  The only time $x-2$ does not have any prime divisor is if $x\in \{1,3\}$ (since $\pm1$ are the only numbers that aren't divisible by a prime).

Comment: True, but in the case where $x-2$ is prime, the **only** prime $n$ such that $x \equiv 2\pmod n$ is $x-2$ itself. This was accounted for in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the first 2 questions boil down to "are there infinitely many numbers 2 more than a prime?" and "4 more than a prime?" Since there are infinitely many primes, the answer to the first 2 questions is a proven yes. The answer to the 3rd is just another avenue for exploring the twin prime conjecture, but thoughts to this end would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For any (not necessarily prime) integer $n>1$ there are infinitely many natural numbers  $m$ with $m\not\equiv 2\pmod n$. Indeed, for any $k$ there are $kn$ natural numbers $\le kn$ and only $k$ of these are $\equiv 2\pmod n$. In fact, any set of $n$ consecutive integers contains $n-1$ numbers $\not\equiv 2\pmod n$.

Comment: I think my ambiguity has confused you. See Thomas's comments under the original post. Rather than "for any $n$, $m\not\equiv 2\pmod n$ for that particular $n$," I mean "**for all prime $n$**, are there infinitely many $m$ such that $m\not\equiv 2\pmod n$." (Still slightly ambiguous, but I think you get what I mean, and I can't think of a way to remove the ambiguity. Any suggestions would be great!)